# Two forms on same page - submitting via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am new to all this and I have two instances of the same form on a page, that I want to submit with Jquery. I hve tinkered with several tutorials, but it seems that the first form only is processed via my method.

I tried using different submit ids, but the function does not trigger, and duplicating the script for each form - but I am not familiar with JS so I couldn't work it out.

FORMS

```
<form name=Form1" action="URL" method="post">
<input type="email" size=65 name="Email" id="Email1" required>
<input type="hidden" name="field1" value="y">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">
</form>

<form name=Form2" action="URL" method="post">
<input type="email" size=65 name="Email" id="Email2" required>
<input type="hidden" name="field1" value="n">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

JS function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').submit(function(event) {

    var formData = {
      'field1': $('input[name=field1]').val(),
      'Email': $('input[name=Email]').val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'URL',
        data: formData,
      })

      .done(function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
          window.location = 'THANK YOU URL';
        }
      });

    event.preventDefault();

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: check `<form name=Form1"` you're missing a quote `"` and put `event.preventDefault();` at first in `function(event)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, and problem solved thx to then answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formdata you are getting is not dynamic. With

```
var formData = {
    'field1': $('input[name=field1]').val(),
    'Email': $('input[name=Email]').val(),
};
```

you will always get the values from the first set of input fields.
If you want the values to depend on the form submitted you need to use [`$(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context)  to get the submitted form and find the corresponding input fields:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = {
      'field1': $(this).find('input[name=field1]').val(),
      'Email': $(this).find('input[name=Email]').val(),
    };

    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'URL',
        data: formData,
      })

      .done(function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
          window.location = 'THANK YOU URL';
        }
      });


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="Form1" action="URL " method="post ">
  <input type="email" size=65 name="Email" id="Email1" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="y">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">
</form>

<form name="Form2" action="URL" method="post">
  <input type="email" size=65 name="Email" id="Email2" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="n">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```